# How to send the status of WebSocket request in ActionCable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket, actioncable

Is there any way to send a status of request to client in ActionCable Channels?

For example, if sent data is invalid (or some unknown exception were raised) I want to error text in response message, otherwise send 'status: ok'. What I have on client side now is subscriber's **perform** method which returns **true** in almost any circumstances as we can see from source code ([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection.coffee#L16)):

```
send: (data) ->
  if @isOpen()
    @webSocket.send(JSON.stringify(data))
    true
  else
    false
```

In [websocket-rails](https://github.com/websocket-rails) gem there were methods for this: **trigger_failure** and **trigger_success**.