# ActionCable - Respond With Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

With ActionCable, how can I respond with an error after receiving data from a client?

For example, when the client fails to authenticate, ActionCable throws `UnauthorizedError` which responds with a 404. I want to respond with a 422, for example, when the data that the client sent is invalid.

Comment: A possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/39650446/5381547

Answer (score 2):

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast "your_channel", message: {data: data, code: 422}
```

Then in `your.coffee` file:

```
received: (res) ->
  switch res.code
    when 200
      # your success code
      # use res.data to access your data message
    when 422
      # your error handler
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I could gather there's no "Rails way" to do this, the answer given by @Viktor seems correct. In summary: ensure all messages are broadcasted with both data and code, then switch by code in the client.

For a more modern and ES6 example see below:

In rails:

```
require 'json/add/exception'

def do_work
  // Do work or raise
  CampaignChannel.broadcast_to(@campaign, data: @campaign.as_json, code: 200)
rescue StandardError => e
  CampaignChannel.broadcast_to(@campaign, data: e.to_json, code: 422) # Actually transmitting the entire stacktrace is a bad idea!
end
```

In ES6:

```
campaignChannel = this.cable.subscriptions.create({ channel: "CampaignChannel", id: campaignId }, {
  received: (response) => {
    const { code, data } = response

    switch (code) {
      case 200:
        console.log(data)
        break
      default:
        console.error(data)
    }
  }
})
```